# How can I build TensorFlow Playground for offline usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, neural-network, tensorflow

I recently tried to use the [TensorFlow Playground Project](https://github.com/tensorflow/playground) and follow what its [README.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/playground/blob/master/README.md) said to do but failed to in process.

This is all I had done:

1. download the project zip from GitHub and extract it.
2. run "npm install" in its root, like what its README said. (I had NodeJS installed before) and everything went fine.
3. then I run "npm run serve" to follow what its README saying, but come up with these lines of errors:

`npm run serve
deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 serve C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground
http-server dist/
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at net.js:1395:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:453:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 serve: http-server dist/
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 serve script 'http-server dist/'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the deep-playground-prototype package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server dist/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground\npm-debug.log`

4. then I think maybe I have to build it first and run "npm run build" and come up with these lines of errors:

`npm run build
deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 build C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground
npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html
deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 prep C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground
typings install && mkdir -p dist && cat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/d3/d3.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js > dist/lib.js
typings WARN deprecated 9/7/2016, 5:27:44 AM: "registry:dt/d3#0.0.0+20160315011939" has been deprecated
└── d3 (ambient)
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "prep"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 prep: typings install && mkdir -p dist && cat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/d3/d3.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js > dist/lib.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 prep script 'typings install && mkdir -p dist && cat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/d3/d3.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js > dist/lib.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the deep-playground-prototype package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install && mkdir -p dist && cat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/d3/d3.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js > dist/lib.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 build: npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deep-playground-prototype@2016.3.10 build script 'npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the deep-playground-prototype package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls deep-playground-prototype
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\AUTUMN16\Computational Intelligence\TensorFlow-Playground\npm-debug.log`

and now I think maybe it have some kind problem with windows or something like that.

I'm a beginner in these kind of works and couldn't find anything online that can help me to solve it. I appreciate any kind of help/guidance/suggestion/anything! that could help me progress in solving it.

Comment: That sounds like an install problem, could you report this to the [github issues](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/playground) page?

Comment: Yep, the `build` script is using a unix-only command, which fails on windows. Specifically, they are using the bash command `cat`. This is an issue with tensorflow.

Comment: I actually reported there before asking here, but there was (and is) no response. thank you for mentioning. @drpng

Comment: Thank you @RyanZim I think I have to try it on Linux, fortunately I have one installed!

Comment: It looks like the issue has been solved, and the solution is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/playground/issues/42

Comment: Hi, is this issue still relevant? I just simplified the instructions on the README on https://github.com/tensorflow/playground and updated to a newer version of http-server which can open a new port if the 8080 is already taken